# Can I ask for source code on this site?

Tags: discussion

I want some "bad code" to use to evaluate and compare static code analyzers.

I asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20074/c-code-for-evaluating-static-code-analysis-tools), but the question is in danger of being closed.

Would it be acceptable here? Is there a better S.E site to ask it?

Comment: Get examples from highly downvoted questions on SO. As long as you keep with the license at the bottom of the page (A creative commons license), you're good to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No It amounts to a question that would fall under the following close reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.